# `FallbackValue` not evaluated on Binding with empty `Path` in WPF XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

On a `Page` with no `DataContext` the fallback value is never evaluated, resulting in a blank `TextBlock` shown.

For example:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{x:Null}" Text="{Binding  FallbackValue='HelloWorld'}"></TextBlock>
```

or

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{x:Null}" Text="{Binding Path='' FallbackValue='HelloWorld'}"></TextBlock>
```

Whereas the following `Binding`, also with a null DataContext **does** show it's `FallbackValue`.

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{x:Null}" Text="{Binding NonExistantProperty, FallbackValue='HelloWorld'}"></TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should you use TargetNullValue instead of FallbackValue in your case.
FallbackValue is used when something is wrong with the Binding path or value.
In you case there is nothing wrong: null value can be bound to the TextBlock.Text.